Javascript class, initialize with object & optional values
I have a few questions regarding the code below:


export class Person {
    constructor(obj = { id: 0, name: '', lastName: '', eyeColor: '', age: 0 }) {
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.name = obj.name;
        this.lastName = obj.lastName;
        this.eyeColor = obj.eyeColor;
        this.age = obj.age;
    }

    yearOfBirth() {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.age;
    }

    json() {
        return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
}



FWIW: I prefer to create an object using this syntax:


let newPerson = new Person(
  { 
    id: 0, 
    name: "Werner", 
    lastName: "Venter", 
    age: 37
  }
);



I really dislike this way:


let newPerson = new Person(0, "Werner", "Venter", 37);



It just reads easier for me when I have the parameter name with the value. Anyway, I digress...

Is this the correct/accepted way to create an object class? I will be using it to receive data from an API that sends it in this format as JSON.
How do I make a parameter optional? Mainly why I need this is that the ID value is not required when creating a new entry on the API, so I would prefer not to include the ID value when creating the object.
Finally, do you have any opinion/advice on this approach?

Thank you in advance guys. Really appreciate this community.

Why are you using a class at all? There is no need here.


Is this the correct/accepted way to create an object class? I will be using it to receive data from an API that sends it in this format as JSON.

Yes, you have created a class which handles some properties of an object, in this way you must pass a class to the constructor. (because you've used statements such as obj.name)

How do I make a parameter optional? Mainly why I need this is that the ID value is not required when creating a new entry on the API, so I would prefer not to include the ID value when creating the object.

You just did, by declaring obj = <some_object>, note that by what you did here, in case no object will be passed when you create a new instance of Person, the default object you have provided will be used as a default value.

let newPerson = new Person(0, "Werner", "Venter", 37);

This one is wrong btw, your constructor method excepts one parameter while in the example above 4 are provided.
This way is the correct one indeed (but it drag an error because eyeColor was not provided):

let newPerson = new Person(
{
id: 0,
name: "Werner",
lastName: "Venter",
age: 37
}
);


Thanks for the reply. When I create a new person and I dont specify the ID value I get this error:
Argument of type '{ name: string; age: number; lastName: string; eyeColor: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: number; name: string; lastName: string; eyeColor: string; age: number; }'.
Property 'id' is missing in type '{ name: string; age: number; lastName: string; eyeColor: string; }' but required in type '{ id: number; name: string; lastName: string; eyeColor: string; age: number; }'.js
Thats why I am asking how to make a parameter (or value in the object?)

optional. Not sure how to mark a value in the parameter as optional.

I think what I meant is: How to I make a KEY optional in the object I am passing

I can't comment on James' answer, he wrote below how to have an optional key, with his snippet if you don't have "id" in your passed object, it will stay "unassigned", if the id key is provided it will be used and assigned to this.id with Object.assign(this, obj)

constructor({ id = 0, name =  '', lastName = '', eyeColor = '', age = 0 } = {}) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
    this.age = age;
}


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

For question 2:
constructor(obj = { id: 0, name: '', lastName: '', eyeColor: '', age: 0 }) {
    this.id = "unassigned"; // whatever default value
    Object.assign(this, obj); // all properties in obj get written to this, if id exists it will overwrite "unassigned"
}


Thanks for this, but I need to make the ID key optional when passing the values. So i would like to create the person as follows: let person = new Person({ age: 20, name: 'Werner'}) then all the keys left out (id, lastName etc) should use the default values.

Then you would need to pre populate all the props that are optional the way I have done with the ID prop (give a default value, then object assign to write in the passed value if it exists)

From what I understand of your question(?), here is what I propose to you.


class Person
  {
  constructor(obj) 
    {
    const
      Defaults = { id:0, name:'', lastName:'', eyeColor:'', age:0 }
    , {id,name,lastname,eyeColor,age} = Object.assign( Defaults , obj)
      ;    
    Object.assign( this , {id,name,lastname,eyeColor,age} );
    }
  yearOfBirth() 
    {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - this.age;
    }
  json() 
    {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
    }
  }
  
let
  Person_A = new Person({ name:'Werner', age: 37 })
, Person_B = new Person({ name:'Brigite', lastname:'Bardot', hair:'blond' })  
  ;

console.log( Person_A.json() );
console.log( Person_B.json() );  //.. hair doesn't apply into



